# Assigning anchors dynamically in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I am creating 2 elements dynamically in QML and need to assign them each an anchor binding. When I add the anchors.right and anchors.left syntax to the properties object of the createObject() function, the anchors are not working:

```
current_column_on_left = column_component.createObject(parent_element, {anchors.right: previous_column_on_left.left})
current_column_on_right = column_component.createObject(parent_element, {anchors.left: previous_column_on_left.right})
```

Qt Creator gives me the annotation/error "Expected token ','". I also tried making them strings and camel case, neither of which worked. However, when I add the property bindings separately using Qt.binding() function, everything works fine:

```
current_column_on_left.anchors.right = Qt.binding(function(){return previous_column_on_left.left})
current_column_on_right.anchors.left = Qt.binding(function(){return previous_column_on_right.right})
```

Why is the first code block not working? I would prefer not to have the two extra lines of code if I can avoid it.

Comment: What is the overarching problem you are trying to solve here? Looks like you actually would want a `Row`/`RowLayout`?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I think the error message is because you are passing a properties object that contains another object (`anchors`) that you are not defining. In other words, I think it would have to be defined more like this: `{anchors: {right: previous_column_on_left.left}}`. But I tried that and it didn't show an error, but it didn't work either. I would just stick with the working code you have.

Comment: @Amfasis I'm working on a "snap while dragging" behavior that will need to dynamically add and remove "snap levels" when the main window is resized. A RowLayout may work, but, for what I need to do, I would have to have multiple RowLayouts, then interact with it's children array which is a pain. I try to avoid doing that if I can.

Comment: @JarMan Thanks for the suggestion. It does not seem to work for me either though.

Comment: FYI you could probably achieve the same thing using QML only with states and `AnchorChange`.

Answer (score 2):

The error is because javascript doesn't know what property groups are - only qml does.

This is also invalid logic. In `createObject(parent_element, {anchors.left: previous_column_on_left.right})` property `previous_column_on_left.right` is resolved when qreating the javascript `{}`-style object, which leaves you bound to a fixed anchor which is never changed. But Qt.binding has a function, and resolves nothing when creating the object, which provides you with the correct binding.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use `createObject()` with anchors properties. The trick is to consider `anchors.fill: parentID` not as a group of properties `anchors: { fill: parentID }` but simply as a single property `"anchors.fill": parentID`.

Note that i use "parentID" and not the reference "parent" because since the object doesn't existe   the property "parent" also doesn't existe.

Also, if there are no better solution to avoid this probleme, it is better to pass the anchors as args for `createObject()` than setting it after it creation, to avoid computing the layout 2 time.